# Android Studio não reconhece alguns comandos

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Alguém sabe como consertar isso? Do nada esses dois comandos pararam de funcionar

Nota: Quando eu executo o aplicativo não dá nenhum erro, mas mesmo assim mostra que tem erros no código por algum motivo

[image: getWindow]
[image: AlertDialog.Builder]

Além disso, mesmo eu usando a função `jogar()` fica mostrando que ela não foi usada ainda, embora o aplicativo rsteja funcionando corretamente sem nenhum bug

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Estou a utilizar a actualização mais recente e, por vezes, tenho o mesmo problema. A solução passa por sair e entrar outra vez, de preferência através de File->Invalidade / Restart.

Comment: Normalmente é cache do Android Studio. Tente limpar utilizando a opção que o @ramaral disse

Answer (score 0):

inosivel, o método `getWindow` só é suportado com projetos que tem no mínimo a versão 23 do android SDK, e no lugar de MainActivity.this use o método `getApplicationContext()` isso se você estiver criando o builder na MainActivity.